# How to validate an input against the current value of a variable (Custom validator function)?

Tags: angular, validation, input, max, customvalidator

I have an input field on my form and need to validate that the number is not greater than 1,000,000 and not less than the account's balance. I was able to set a max of 1,000,000 but have not been able to successfully compare the balance to the input. I would like this to result in a red outline around the input field, similar to the when it is over 1,000,000. Here is my code:

**HTML template**

```
<mat-form-field appearance = outline class="amount">
  <mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
  <input matInput
    type='number'
    required 
    formControlName="amount">
</mat-form-field>
```

**Component**

```js
export class StartComponent implements OnInit {
  currentAccount: ICustomerAccount;
  amountMax = 1000000;
  startForm = new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl('', Validators.max(this.amountMax)),
  });
}
```

Comment: Does the balance change during the lifetime of the form - does the comparison need to be dynamic or can it be static at point of creating the form?

Comment: The balance is changing. The balance is being pulled from the customer account  service. It's currently being referenced as currentAccount.currentBalance

Comment: See above reply ^^ @KurtHamilton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a CustomValidator function, as described here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-validator-test',
  templateUrl: './validator-test.component.html'
})
export class ValidatorTestComponent implements OnInit {
  public startForm: FormGroup;
  public amountMax = 5000;
  public currentAccount: any = {value: 10};

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.startForm =  this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: ['', [Validators.max(this.amountMax), this.customValidatorFn()]]
    });
  }

  private customValidatorFn(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const valid: boolean = this.currentAccount.value <= control.value;
      return valid ? null : {amountMinError: true};
    };
  }
}
```

template:

```
<form [formGroup]="startForm" *ngIf="startForm">
  <input formControlName="amount" type="number"/>
  <div>valid: {{startForm.get('amount').valid}}</div>
</form>
```

don't forget to add FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule to the module imports: `imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],`

Comment: Where exactly should this go in the file? When i insert it, it makes every other function unreadable. and return has an error saying it expects an expression. @Nadine

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm sorry, the code was really not able to run because of several freestyle errors. I corrected it now in my IDE. Please try again :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the revision. Now there are no errors but it is not highlighting the input field in red when it is false

Comment: now it should finally be a complete working example. The red highlighting for this kind of error potentially needs to be implemented (add an error-message or style for the amountMinError kind)